# Zsh tab-completion for "cd .."

Tags: macos, shell, autocomplete, zsh

How can I configure the Zsh tab-completion such that when I type `cd ..<TAB>` it expands to `cd ../` and after pressing `<TAB>` again proposes the folders in the parent directory for completion?

E.g. it should show the same behavior as when typing for example `cd Documents<TAB>` which expands to `cd Documents/` and after pressing `<TAB>` again proposes the folders in `Documents` for completion.

As a starting point for configuration I use an empty `.zshrc` and Zsh 4.3.9 from MacPorts.

Comment: for a long time I had this doubt

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Same problem with debian unstable, Ubuntu jaunty, both ship zsh 4.3.9. I know of multiple people with different configurations.

After reading http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=514152 I added

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
```

to my config and now  everything works fine again.

Comment: `man zshcompsys` also suggests this:
`zstyle -e ':completion:*' special-dirs '[[ $PREFIX = (../)#(|.|..) ]] && reply=(..)'` which avoids "./" and "../" being proposed all the time.

Comment: @exic how is your code different to the answer? Your code also gives a slash each time after tab after two dots.

Comment: Just for clarity, put this in `.zshrc`, it didn't work when i added it to `.zprofile`.

Answer (score 11):

Put this into your ~/.zshrc:

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

---

There is also a project with zsh functions/configurations for Mac OS X on http://code.google.com/p/zsh-templates-osx/ . Personally I think it's an overkill to use the whole package. But found it useful to cherry pick some tricks, functions, completions etc. and create my own .zshrc

Comment: Thank you, this configures exactly the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: What does the option z does in your code?

Comment: autload commandline options:
-U  -- suppress alias expansion for functions
-k  -- mark function for ksh-style autoloading
-t  -- turn on execution tracing for functions
-w  -- specify that arguments refer to files compiled with zcompile
-z  -- mark function for zsh-style autoloading

Comment: But... I have that in my .zshrc and my `.` and `..` folders don't get completed. :P What is going on there?

Comment: I learned that the top vote answer is preferred and this answer does not always work according to @VictorZamanian , so why keep this answer?

Answer (score -16):

This may or may not be a useful answer - switch to **bash**, which does what you want out of the box.

Comment: That's somewhat like telling an vim user to switch to emacs, because he can't find a configuration switch... IMHO zsh is more powerful than bash and also comes with a great completion function. You just have to activate it...