# How can I add completion in zsh on macOS for 'cd ..'?

Tags: macos, zsh, completion

I found some questions and answers on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

Comment: PLease add some detail on what you have tried: which SO questions / answers have you tried and found unhelpful. What did you implement (if possible include code) that did not work?

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564648/zsh-tab-completion-for-cd and was not able to comment because of my low reputation. So I had to create a new topic.

    The accepted answer was correct but not exhaustive:
    "zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true"
After that the following code has to be inserted too:
"autoload -Uz compinit
compinit"

Comment: Also the rule to only be able to comment for five minutes is not helpful.

Answer (score 5):

My solution is to put this into ~/.zshrc:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' special-dirs true
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
```

This works for me on macOS 10.15.4 with zsh 5.7.1.

I couldn't answer or comment on the exiting because my 'reputation' was too low.